# Locking cells after data entry

Tags: vba, excel, timestamp

I need to lock each cell after data entry in given range. Like once I enter Y or N in it so no one can edit it again. below is my code, any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, MyPass As String, sh As Worksheet
Dim unit As Range
Set A = Range("E10:E22")
MyPass = "a"
Set sh = ActiveSheet
If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Set unit = Union(Target, Target.Offset(0, 1), Target.Offset(0, 2), Target.Offset(0, 3))
Application.EnableEvents = False
sh.Unprotect (MyPass)
unit.Locked = False
Target.Offset(0, 1) = Environ("Username")
Target.Offset(0, 2) = Now()
Target.Offset(0, 3) = Now()
unit.Locked = True
sh.protect (MyPass)
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code? any errors? in which line and what kind of error?

Comment: Thanks for looking over it. Nothing is wrong with the code but I want to lock the cells post entry and no one can edit that cell once again.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed a number of your variables as direct referencing was all that was needed and the *Set* ranges you created were never set to nothing. Assuming that the worksheet is currently protected with E10:E22 unlocked, the following should work the way you intended.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E10:E22")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim MyPass As String: MyPass = "a"
        Me.Unprotect MyPass
        'Target.Resize(1, 4).Locked = False  ' ◄ not needed when the sheet is unprotected
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 3) = Array(Environ("Username"), Now(), Now())
        Target.Resize(1, 4).Locked = True
        Me.Protect MyPass
    End If
Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have tried it but again it is locking other cells, like I have entered in E10 then E11,E12.... is locked for editing. I need E10:E22 to be locked after each entry. Moreover I have tried with allowing users to edit ranges but it is also not working. Help out on this.

Comment: It sounds like you never unlocked E10:E22 to start with. Cells are (by default) in a locked state (e.g. `Cell.Locked = True`) but the actual locking is performed by protecting the worksheet. Please reread the first paragraph of my answer. If you want the remaining cells to be able to accept input after you have protected the worksheet, they must start as `Cell.Locked = False`. Use `Ctrl+1` then access the *Protection* tab to start them off as unlocked. The sub will lock each as it received input.

Comment: Many thanks Jeeped. Actually I was not unlocking the range but once you elaborated it in detail and it helped resolving the cause. Appreciate it.